# How to optimize this database structure?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

For a future project I'm planning I'll have three tables.

The 1st keeps track of the recipe information, the 2nd keeps track labels which references the recipe_id from the recipe table, the 3rd table contains a list of all the ingredients.

```
recipe:
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| id [AI] |  title          |  category   |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+ 
| 20      |  Italian Pizza  |   dinner    |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 21      |  Greek Soup     |   lunch     |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+

recipe_ingredients_label:
+---------------+------------+-------------+
| label_id [AI] |  recipe_id |    label    |
+---------------+------------+-------------+ 
| 1             |  20        |  Pizza Base |
+---------------+------------+-------------+
| 2             |  20        |   Topping   |
+---------------+------------+-------------+

recipe_ingredients:
+----------+------------+----------------------+
| label_id |   amount   |   ingredients        |
+----------+------------+----------------------+ 
|    1     |   4 cups   |   Cheese             |
+----------+------------+----------------------+ 
|    1     |   3/4 cup  |   White Flour        |
+----------+------------+----------------------+ 
|    2     |   1 cup    |   Mozzarella Cheese  |
+----------+------------+----------------------+ 
|    2     |   1/2 cup  |   Tomato Sauce       |
+----------+------------+----------------------+
```

The recipe_ingredients references the recipe_ingredients_label table, each ingredient goes under it's own label like so:

**Pizza Base** contains *4 cups cheese, 3/4 cup white flour*.

**Topping** contains *1 cup mozzarela cheese, 1/2 cup tomato sauce*.

The issue is that not all recipes contains labels, so I'd like to make the labels optional based on the recipe.

**I thought of this:**

Creating an extra recipe_id column in the recipe_ingredients table, and during insertion to database if no label is found, just reference the recipe_id there instead like so:

```
recipe_ingredients:
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| label_id |  recipe_id |   amount   |   ingredients        |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+ 
|    1     |    NULL    |   4 cups   |   Cheese             |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
|    1     |    NULL    |   3/4 cup  |   White Flour        |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+ 
|    2     |    NULL    |   1 cup    |   Mozzarella Cheese  |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
|    2     |    NULL    |   1/2 cup  |   Tomato Sauce       |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
|   NULL   |     21     |   2 cups   |   Chicken            |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
|   NULL   |     21     |   1/2 cup  |   Half carrots       |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
|   NULL   |     21     |      2     |   Celery stalks      |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Is this the best way to organize/optimize this table for performance and less data thrown all over the database? What would you recommend?

Comment: I would have kipped the __recipe_id__ label with 20 and 21 in it and add a subsection __label__ (or something like that) which can be __Topping__ or _Pizza_base__ (and not  a number) and indicate the subsection reference. For the soup, you just put not label. It´s better because you have one main label (always full) and a subsection.

Comment: Thing is that the labels are dynamic, unless I misunderstood what you meant I couldn't follow that logic.

Comment: I didn´t realized that. Why not putting a default label_id at zero/NULL to say there is not sub-recipe but always keep the recipe_id as a reference. Anyway excepted if you are planning to have millions of recipes, the processing time should not be very different between all your proposals.